# Getting TypeError with speech_recognition module in Python

Tags: python-2.7, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to convert speech to text in real time using the module `SpeechRecognition 3.4.6` I've installed everything and now I am trying a simple code from example, here's the code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

# recognize speech using Sphinx
try:
    print("Sphinx thinks you said " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
     print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
     print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

I am getting error at line `audio = r.listen(source)`, the error traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sr.py", line 4, in <module>
audio = r.listen(source)                   # listen for the first    phrase and extract it into audio data
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-  packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 493, in listen
 buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 139, in read
  return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow = False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
 return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
 TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pyaudio 0.2.9, it seems you have older version

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the version of python is too old.